# MongoWriteConcernError: No write concern mode named 'majority;' found in replica set configuration at MessageStream.messageHandler

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am using createTask function to insert the document in mongodb atlas , the document is getting saved in atlas but catch part is also working and hence res.send after inserting document is not working.

```
const createTask=async (req,res)=>{
    try{
      const task = await Task.create(req.body);
    //   res.status(201).json({task});
        res.send('done');
    }
    catch(err){res.status(500).json({msg:err});}
}
```

When I send the error using catch the error is coming as-

```
"msg": {
        "code": 79,
        "codeName": "UnknownReplWriteConcern",
        "errInfo": {
            "writeConcern": {
                "w": "majority;",
                "wtimeout": 0,
                "provenance": "clientSupplied"
            }
        },
        "name": "MongoWriteConcernError",
        "result": {
            "n": 1,
            "opTime": {
                "ts": "7021011505814437896",
                "t": 192
            },
            "electionId": "7fffffff00000000000000c0",
            "ok": 1,
            "writeConcernError": {
                "code": 79,
                "codeName": "UnknownReplWriteConcern",
                "errmsg": "No write concern mode named 'majority;' found in replica set configuration",
                "errInfo": {
                    "writeConcern": {
                        "w": "majority;",
                        "wtimeout": 0,
                        "provenance": "clientSupplied"
                    }
                }
            },
            "$clusterTime": {
                "clusterTime": "7021011505814437896",
                "signature": {
                    "hash": "C1HLM9Tmi+sPwFdXIPTEATVpmuA=",
                    "keyId": "6978775665008967681"
                }
            },
            "operationTime": "7021011505814437896"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This Error occurs beacuse of your database string, just remove "&w=majority" from the end of setup string.

> `DB = "mongodb+srv://name:Password@cluster0.f60fb.mongodb.net/mernstack?retryWrites=true&w=majority"`

instead write as

> `DB = "mongodb+srv://name:Password@cluster0.f60fb.mongodb.net/mernstack?retryWrites=true"`

hopefully error is gone now.

if still error exists, then check any spaces at the end or rewrite your string. hopefully this will crack.

Answer (score 2):

In your `.env` file remove `&w=majoritytatus(400)` from them uri to get the below

```
mondb_uri=mongodb+srv://name:Password@cluster0.f60fb.mongodb.net/mernstack?retryWrites=true
```

Remember to re-run whenever you edit `.env` files

Answer (score 1):

write it like this, without any quotes and semicolon;

```
mongodb+srv://name:<password>@cluster0.qxgva.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Never write it like this.

```
mongodb+srv://name:<pwd>@cluster0.qxgva.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority;
```

or like this

```
"mongodb+srv://name:<pwd>@cluster0.qxgva.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DB = mongodb+srv://name:Password@cluster0.f60fb.mongodb.net/mernstack?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

I just write the above query as below and it will work for me(just provided quotes)

```
DB = "mongodb+srv://name:Password@cluster0.f60fb.mongodb.net/mernstack?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);

main().catch(err => console.log(err));
async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://user:<password>@database.w441exx.mongodb.net/Database');
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Actually we have wrote the connection string as `"mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.hu0mpdv.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority"`

**By removing '&w=majority' I have solved this problem**

***And then restart my program***

Answer (score 0):

Finally i gotted solution, reason is we are using extra db_name in connection string like that

```
const mongooseInstance = await mongoose.connect(`${process.env.MONGO_URI}/${DB_NAME}`);
```

dont add DB_NAME because of mongo atlas already contains that db-name like that

```
const mongooseInstance = await mongoose.connect(`${process.env.MONGO_URI}`);
```